# How to mount samba drive in Linux using command line

Tags: networking, mount, samba, drive, network-drive

I've got a shared folder on a Windows computer, and I'd like to mount it on a server running Ubuntu Server.

How can I mount a samba drive from the command line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, unless already installed, install `cifs-utils` as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install cifs-utils
```

Then, choose a path where to place a file containing the credentials to access your shared folder. Let's say `/home/.smbcredentials`, as an instance.
So, open that file and write your credentials as follows:

```
username=yourUsername
password=yourPassword
```

Also, decide where to mount your shared folder. Let's say `/myfolder`, as an instance (make sure this folder exists otherwise, create it with 'mkdir').

Now, assuming you want your network folder to be accessible as soon as your Linux system is started, edit the `/etc/fstab` file. You can use `nano` as follows:

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

Then, you should be able to see something already written to that file. Therefore, just append one line to the bottom:

```
//yourHostNameOrIpAddress/path/to/your/shared/folder  /your/mount/point  cifs  guest,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,credentials=/path/to/the/credentials/file
```

That's all, reboot your Linux system by typing `reboot -f` and your network drive will be mounted.

As an alternative to rebooting, running `/etc/fstab` as superuser should work:

```
sudo /etc/fstab
```

Comment: Other ways to mount the new drive: `sudo mount /your/mount/point` (mount that drive using the settings in /etc/fstab) or `sudo mount -a` (mount all drives listed in /etc/fstab)

Answer (score 1):

First install cifs-utils. This will make the mount.cifs command available.

Next create a mount point in your local filesystem where the remote filesystem will appear after it is monted:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/mount-point
```

Then mount the remote samba drive:

```
sudo mount.cifs //server/share /mnt/mount-point
```

See `man mount.cifs` for other options. If a password is needed, you will be prompted for it.